# CMake for Tesseract and OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, tesseract

I am new to Linux programming, I am trying create an OCR application on `Ubuntu 12.10` using [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/%E2%80%8E) and [OpenCV](http://www.opencv.org). So far I have setup `tesseract` and `OpenCV` on linux also I have followed this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html), in this tutorial I found it very easy that we create one file `CMakeList.txt` and link OpenCV in it.

Now I am trying to compile `tesseract-ocr` library with [this code](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample#Basic_example). As I know I did not make a link between `tesseract-ocr` and my code and thats why I am having errors.

All I want and searching for is if I can link `Tesseract` and `OpenCV` using `CMake` in one file, if it is possible. A tutorial would be good as I am totally new to Linux. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a *CMakeLists.txt* like this

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (test-ocr)

# Add the including directory of the tesseract 
# and please replace with your dir.
include_directories (/home/ytxie/include)
# Add the search directory for the tesseract library 
# and please replace with your dir.
link_directories (/home/ytxie/lib)

add_executable (test-ocr test.cpp)

# link the leptonica library and the tesseract library
target_link_libraries (test-ocr lept tesseract)
```

I've add comments and it seems easy to understand. The *test.cpp* is just the [that example code](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample#Basic_example).

And if you want to add OpenCV relating setting into this cmake file, just add them. If there are some confusing things please read the [CMake's document](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html).

NOTE: to make the *test-ocr* run successfully, you should download the [English data](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz&can=2&q=) and copy it's content into the */share/tessdata*.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, I have two questions. Do I need to include and link directories for both "tesseract" and "lept" ? I am trying to find libraries using command `pkg-config --cflags tesseract` and `pkg-config --cflags lept` and it is throwing me errors. I dont know where exactly these libraries are as I have installed them many times

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz There are linking search directories defined by **ldconfig** and you can Google it to find more information. In my computer, *lept* is installed on the */usr/lib* which is within the search set defined by **ldconfig** so I didn't add it specifically. But I installed *tesseract* in my home directory which is not in the search set mentioned above and I must tell CMake how to find this library.

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz I'm sorry I don't know why `pkg-config --cflags lept` return error. **pkg-config** find information of a library by finding it's corresponding *pc* file in directories such as */usr/lib/pkgconfig* and */usr/local/lib/pkgconfig* etc.. But I don't know why there's not a *liblept.pc* file.